# S3 Bucket non-encrypted HLS works, but CloudFront of it doesn’t

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

As the title says. S3 Bucket non-encrypted HLS works, but CloudFront of it doesn’t. I have been trying to get it to work for hours without any success. I followed all the docs closely. I set up header whitelist on CloudFront as well. Please help? When playing the video I get `Network error` message. It plays without any problem with the S3 Bucket URL. I tried various HLS streaming test websites.

Comment: What happened when you try to access m3u8 file ? Can you perform a curl on it using cloudfornt link ?

Comment: @JamesDean When using the S3 bucket URL, it opens up without any problems. But the CloudFront reports network error.  This only happens when using signed URLs. When turning that off in CouldFront, it works. I am passing the correct credentials for signed URLs.

Comment: signed URLs causes 403 , I'm not sure what is causing Network error but I assume you're using a player where you're embedding the cloudfront link, it may be incorrectly defined, not enough information to find out whats wrong.

Comment: Yes embedding, but I take the same embedding URL and use it on the browser and it starts a download of the .m3u8 file. The signed URL is validating via browser, just not connecting for the stream. If this hasn't happened on third-party HLS stream test I would have thought it was the player's fault. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

HLS encryption does not work with Sign URL. With HLS encryption we break the video in multiple files (.ts) so if we want our playlist file (.m3u8) can able to access all those .ts files then we need to access those .ts files through signed cookie only.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and resolved it by making the following configuration changes:

1. Open the **Edit behavior** settings for your HLS video origin.
2. Under **Cache key and Origin requests** -> select **Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)**
3. Under **Cache Policy** -> Select **Elemental-MediaPackage**